# Order By in Oracle cause ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, distinct

I have the below query.  When executed it throws an error and the query is not executed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT svc.column1 ,
  svc.column2 ,
  svc.column3 ,
  svc.column4 ,
  svc.column5 ,
  svc.column6 ,
  svc.column7 ,
  svc.column8 ,
  svc.column9 ,
  svc.column10 ,
  svc.column11 ,
  svc.column12
FROM shemaName.tableName svc
WHERE svc.column13 IS NOT NULL
AND svc.column14    = 'DEEPAK'
AND svc.column15    = '188888'
AND ROWNUM         <=10
AND column16        = 'N'
ORDER BY svc.column13;
```

And the error I got was

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression.

The query returns result when `order by` clause is removed, as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT svc.column1 ,
  svc.column2 ,
  svc.column3 ,
  svc.column4 ,
  svc.column5 ,
  svc.column6 ,
  svc.column7 ,
  svc.column8 ,
  svc.column9 ,
  svc.column10 ,
  svc.column11 ,
  svc.column12
FROM shemaName.tableName svc
WHERE svc.column13 IS NOT NULL
AND svc.column14    = 'DEEPAK'
AND svc.column15    = '188888'
AND ROWNUM         <=10
AND column16        = 'N';
```

What is wrong in adding `order by` clause?

Comment: See [DISTINCT results in ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507060/distinct-results-in-ora-01791-not-a-selected-expression)

Answer (score 3):

The engine cannot process your query because it defies logic. I'll give you an lighter example to understand easier the case:

```
Table
colA  colB
1     10
1     30
2     20
2     20
```

So:

```
 select distinct colA from table;
```

> 1
>   2

```
select colA from table order by colb;
```

> 1
>   2
>   2
>   1

BUT, `select distinct colA from table order by colb;` what shoud give? the value 1 should be first and last in the same time. This is an impossible problem.

PS: In your case it may be appropriate to add column13 to the select distinct clause. The query will run fine in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The DISTINCT filters out duplicate values of columns 1-12.  So the result set does not match 1:1 with the rows in your table.

Now your ORDER BY clause asks the database to sort the result set using a column which is not in the result set.  But there may be multiple values of `column13` for each combination of columns 1-12.  The database does not - cannot - know which one to use, so it hurls ORA-01791.

As to a solution, you need a way to expose `column13` to the database without including it in the final projection.  So probably you need to use an in-line of some sort.  Which approach to take depends on your data.

If `column13` has only one value for each combination of columns 1-12 then you can use an in-line view like this:

```
SELECT q.column1 ,
  q.column2 ,
  q.column3 ,
  q.column4 ,
  q.column5 ,
  q.column6 ,
  q.column7 ,
  q.column8 ,
  q.column9 ,
  q.column10 ,
  q.column11 ,
  q.column12
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT svc.column1 ,
              svc.column2 ,
              svc.column3 ,
              svc.column4 ,
              svc.column5 ,
              svc.column6 ,
              svc.column7 ,
              svc.column8 ,
              svc.column9 ,
              svc.column10 ,
              svc.column11 ,
              svc.column12 ,
              svc.column13
        FROM shemaName.tableName svc
        WHERE svc.column13 IS NOT NULL
        AND svc.column14    = 'DEEPAK'
        AND svc.column15    = '188888'
        AND ROWNUM         <=10
        AND column16        = 'N' 
      ) q
order by q.column13;
```

If there *are* multiple values for `column13` choose some restricting criterion and aggregate on that in an in-line view.  This one chooses the lowest value of `column13`:

```
SELECT q.column1 ,
  q.column2 ,
  q.column3 ,
  q.column4 ,
  q.column5 ,
  q.column6 ,
  q.column7 ,
  q.column8 ,
  q.column9 ,
  q.column10 ,
  q.column11 ,
  q.column12
FROM ( SELECT svc.column1 ,
              svc.column2 ,
              svc.column3 ,
              svc.column4 ,
              svc.column5 ,
              svc.column6 ,
              svc.column7 ,
              svc.column8 ,
              svc.column9 ,
              svc.column10 ,
              svc.column11 ,
              svc.column12 ,
              min(svc.column13) as column13
        FROM shemaName.tableName svc
        WHERE svc.column13 IS NOT NULL
        AND svc.column14    = 'DEEPAK'
        AND svc.column15    = '188888'
        AND ROWNUM         <=10
        AND column16        = 'N' 
        group by svc.column1 ,
                  svc.column2 ,
                  svc.column3 ,
                  svc.column4 ,
                  svc.column5 ,
                  svc.column6 ,
                  svc.column7 ,
                  svc.column8 ,
                  svc.column9 ,
                  svc.column10 ,
                  svc.column11 ,
                  svc.column12 
      ) q
order by q.column13;
```

Alternatively, just include `column13` in the DISTINCT projection and accept the multiplication of values.

Comment: Thank you..Understood the problem

Answer (score 0):

One simple mistake you have done was, svc.column13 column not defined in the DISTINCT COLUMNS. So, the engine was not treating the statement as SELECT expression.