# DISTINCT date value in ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to get the unique date values from order table using oracle query. I am getting

> ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

error, When i tried this below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (TO_DATE(LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'))
    FROM ORDER
   WHERE LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP DESC;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have a table called ORDER?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DISTINCT results in ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507060/distinct-results-in-ora-01791-not-a-selected-expression)

Comment: Do you really store your timestamps as strings? You shouldn't.

Comment: @Aleksej, Yes, the table name called "ORDER"

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I am using Timestamp as a Date Datetype, Its stored with Seconds, But here i want till minutes. in that i want to get the unique records.

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. Putting the list of columns inside parentheses makes no sense (or difference)

Comment: Then you are using the wrong function. `TO_DATE` converts a string to a datetime, so your expression silently converts `LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP` to a string first, thereby relying on current settings which can fail. Use `TRUNC(LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP, 'MI')` instead.

Comment: When `SELECT DISTINCT`, only select list items may be used in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3):

`LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP` is not in your result list, because you have aggregated your rows with `DISTINCT` to a truncated timestamp. You can only order by this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP, 'MI')
    FROM ORDER
   WHERE LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TRUNC(LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP, 'MI') DESC;
```

If you don't want to repeat the expression use positional sort:

```
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Or use an alias for the expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP, 'MI') AS LAST_INSERT
    FROM ORDER
   WHERE LAST_INSERT_TIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY LAST_INSERT DESC;
```

Please note that I replaced your `TO_DATE` with the appropriate `TRUNC` because all you want to do is truncate your timestamp, not convert to and from string.